# Defining a column using dbms_sql

Tags: plsql

I get an `pls-00307` ERROR WHERE it says that " string " matches too many object table aliases. What does this mean? 
I get an highlight for section 4 DEFINE COLUMN When I try to define a column in the IF statements over, Why is this happening? Can anyone guide me through this? Thanks!

```
IF ((pStartDate IS NOT NULL) AND (pEndDate IS NOT NULL) AND
     (pStartDate < pEndDate)) THEN


IF ((pIdType IS NOT NULL) AND (pId IS NOT NULL)) THEN
  loSqLText1 := ' CBP.CBP_ID_TYPE, CBP.CBP_ID AS  ';
  loSqLText2 := ' CBP_ID_TYPE, CBP_ID ';
  loSqLText3 := ' CBP_ID_TYPE = :pidtype AND CBP_ID = :pid ';
END IF;

IF ((pName IS NOT NULL) AND (pSurname IS NOT NULL)) THEN
  loSqLText1 := ' CBP.CBP_NAME, CBP.Cbp_Surname ';
  loSqLText2 := ' CBP_NAME , CBP_SURNAME ';
  loSqLText3 := ' CBP_NAME = :pname AND CBP_SURNAME = :psurname ';
END IF;
END IF;

  --1 Query

  loQuery := 'SELECT ' || loSqLText1 ||
         ' , IN_OUT_DATES.IN_COUNT, IN_OUT_DATES.OUT_COUNT  
         FROM 
           (SELECT HBP_PERSON , COUNT(HBP_IN_DATE) IN_COUNT , COUNT(HBP_OUT_DATE) OUT_COUNT 
             FROM HIST_BANNED_PERSONS WHERE HBP_IN_DATE BETWEEN 
              to_date('':pstartdate'',''mm/dd/yyyy'') AND to_date( '':penddate'' , ''mm/dd/yyyy'' )
              GROUP BY HBP_PERSON ) IN_OUT_DATES
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              (SELECT CBP_ROWID, ' || loSqLText2 ||
         ' FROM CHECK_BANNED_PERSONS WHERE ' || loSqLText3 ||
         ' ) CBP
              ON IN_OUT_DATES.HBP_PERSON = CBP.CBP_ROWID ';
  --2 OPEN CURSOR



loCursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor();

  --3 PARSE
  dbms_sql.parse(loCursor, loQuery, dbms_sql.native);

  --4 DEFINE COLUMN 
  IF ((pIdType IS NOT NULL) AND (pId IS NOT NULL)) THEN
    dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 1, loIdType);
    dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 2, loId);
  END IF;

  IF ((pName IS NOT NULL) AND (pSurname IS NOT NULL)) THEN
    dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 1, loName);
    dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 2, loSurname);
  END IF;

  dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 3, loInDate);
  dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 4, loOutDate);
```

The error message I get points the following lines:

```
dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 1, loIdType);
dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 2, loId);

dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 1, loName);
dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 2, loSurname);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, your variables `loIdType`, `loId`, `loName`, and `loSurname` have `VARCHAR2` type. In this case, add a parameter to define variable length:

```
dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 1, loIdType, 4000);
dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 2, loId, 4000);

dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 1, loName, 4000);
dbms_sql.define_column(loCursor, 2, loSurname, 4000);
```

Comment: THANKS!  YOU are a life saver, I can't believe I missed it!